# How do I know if async operation is pending? async pipe in template

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to show a proper message either loading or no items. For now I use the following template.

But how do I know if the async operation is still pending? So I can display separate messages for loading and no items?

```
<div *ngIf="items$ | async as items; else noItems">
  There are {{ items.length }} items
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{ item.name }}
  </div>
</div>
<ng-template #noItems>
  Unfortunately there are no items OR they are still loading
</ng-template>
```

Comment: In this case, I think directly subscribing to `items$` makes more sense than using the async pipe. Do you need to use it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16982) on Github because the initial `null` cannot be distinguished from an actual `null` value from the `Observable`.

As a workaround: If empty array does not convey meaning yet, you could use `[]` instead of `null` for "no items". For that, either change your backend response (if it's a request) or remap the `Observable`'s value.

```
items$ = items$.pipe(map(v => v === null ? [] : v))
```

I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/async-pipe-loading-indicator?file=app/async-promise-pipe.ts) illustrating my idea:

```
<ng-template let-items [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: items$ | async }" [ngTemplateOutlet]="t" #t>
  <span *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</span>
  <span *ngIf="items === null">items is loading for 3 seconds</span>
  <span *ngIf="items?.length === 0">items resolved empty</span>
</ng-template>
```

class:

```
// This is what you get from your service
this.items$ = of(null).pipe(delay(3000));

// Map null to empty array
this.items$ = this.items$.pipe(map(v => v === null ? [] : v))
```